# Which one is more accurate Solve or NSolve? How can I get the same result as Solve using NSolve in the given code?

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, numerics, numerical-value, precision-and-accuracy

I am using this code to calculate the quantity $sol$. Using `Solve`, I get the result $9.8598$

```
g := Sin[2 x \[Pi]]^2 - ((-(1/4) (-1 + Sqrt[5]) Sin[(x \[Pi])/10] +  Sin[(21 x \[Pi])/10])^2)  ;  
t = FunctionPeriod[    g   , x   ];
s = x /. Solve[ g == 0 && 0 < x < t, WorkingPrecision -> 100];  
f = Sort[s, Less];

sol=N[Total @ Differences[f][[;; ;; 2]]]

(*9.8598*)
```

and using `NSolve`, I get the result $9.80485$

```
g := Sin[2 x \[Pi]]^2 - ((-(1/4) (-1 + Sqrt[5]) Sin[(x \[Pi])/10] +  Sin[(21 x \[Pi])/10])^2)  ;  
t = FunctionPeriod[    g   , x   ];
s = x /. NSolve[ g == 0 && 0 < x < t, WorkingPrecision -> 100];  
f = Sort[s, Less];

sol=N[Total @ Differences[f][[;; ;; 2]]]

(*9.80485*)
```

Which of these results is more accurate? I am pressed for time and I need to do this calculation for a much more complicated function which `NSolve` can provide the result faster; how can I get the same result using `NSolve` as `Solve`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

g := Sin[2 x π]^2 - ((-(1/4) (-1 + Sqrt[5]) Sin[(x π)/10] + 
       Sin[(21 x π)/10])^2);
t = FunctionPeriod[g, x];

s[1] = x /. Solve[g == 0 && 0 < x < t, WorkingPrecision -> 100];
f1 = Sort[s[1], Less];

N[Total@Differences[f1][[;; ;; 2]]]

(* 9.80485 *)

s[2] = x /. NSolve[g == 0 && 0 < x < t, WorkingPrecision -> 100];
f2 = Sort[s[2], Less];

N[Total@Differences[f2][[;; ;; 2]]]

(* 9.80485 *)

s[3] = x /. Solve[g == 0 && 0 < x < t];
f3 = Sort[s[3], Less];

N[Total@Differences[f3][[;; ;; 2]]]

(* 9.8598 *)
```

The exact solution includes one additional root

```
Length /@ {f1, f2, f3}

(* {81, 81, 82} *)
```

The additional solution is because the exact solution includes the double root at `x == 10`

```
(Select[s[#], Abs[# - 10] < 10^-6 &] & /@ Range[3]) /. x_Real :> N[x]

(* {{10.}, {10.}, {10, 10}} *)

Plot[g, {x, 9.5, 10.5},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[3],
   Point[{#, g /. x -> #} & /@ s[1]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, yes, I also checked, NSolve gives a double root which should be removed from my calculation.